# How do I convert a beamer based LaTeX file to HTML?

Tags: beamer, conversion, html

I have a LaTeX `beamer`-based presentation that I would like to convert to HTML. How do I go about it?
I've tried the typical LaTeX to HTML translators (eg. [tth](http://hutchinson.belmont.ma.us/tth/)). But they do not handle `beamer` presentations.

Comment: What sort of output do you want?  A beamer presentation consists of lots of pages, each with an incremental transition.  Surely you don't want all of those!  Beamer presentations also tend to be very visual, how accurate do you want the visual stuff to be?

Comment: I am not interested in transitions. I have a bot generated beamer presentation with images that I'd like to convert to html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `text4ht`, as @Raphink says. However, I'm not familiar with the `mk4ht` command. On Windows I use `htlatex` alone and it works most of the time. Before I address the solution, here are some assumptions:

1. You have `htlatex` in your environment path. That means, that in a command prompt you can use it just by typing `htlatex`, and it will execute the command. If you don't have it in your environment variables, you should use the full path to the command.
2. You should be in the directory in which you have your `.tex` files. You need to move using `cd /d F:\path\to\your\files` (The `/d` option changes the drive in case is different from the one you are in now).

So, the solution is quite simple, you have to type in the command prompt: `htlatex file.tex html "" -dhtml "--interaction=nonstopmode"`. 
So what it does? you may ask. The `file.tex` is your file, `html` is the output format, `-dhtml` is the directory in which the output should be written, in this case the directory is named `html`, you can change it to anything, for example, `-dmydir`, and finally the `"--interaction=nonstopmode"` is a parameter passed to the compilation so it doesn't stop for answers.

If you want, you can use an script I made, it is in [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39458/7561). You can place it in your directory and just execute it, or place it somewhere in your environment path and use it anywhere.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of `latex2html`, I'd recommend using `tex4ht`, like the following:

```
mk4ht htlatex yourproject.tex 'xhtml,charset=utf-8' ' -cunihtf -utf8 -cvalidate'
```

Comment: I'm on windows & see the following exe's in the bin directory of tex4ht - 1.tex4ht 2.t4ht 3.htcmd ... there is no mk4ht. Am i missing something ?

Comment: I have no clue about the Windows install. Maybe try these and see if they will do.

Comment: I get an ugly mess doing that. Doesn't work, period.