# Using htlatex to convert LaTeX to HTML

Tags: miktex, conversion, windows, tex4ht

I appear to have `htlatex` and `htxelatex` already installed on my computer.  However when I try to run them, it comes up with the message, `'I can't write on file 'texput.log''`

I am trying to convert a LaTeX file to HTML.

This is on Windows, with MiKTeX.

Comment: What OS and TeX distributon are you using? How are you invoking `htlatex` (from an editor? from the command line?)

Comment: I am using Miktex 2.9   I don't know what an OS distribution is.  I am clicking on the start button in the bottom left hand corner and typing in htlatex into the Search programmes and files box.  When htlatex comes up I click on it and another box with a black background appears with a lot of text concluding with the statement 'I can't write on file  'texput.log''

Comment: TeX4ht is also included in the TeXLive a standard distribution of TeX and friends for Unix and Unix like systems. It looks like you are using Windows operating system as MiKTeX is the standard distribution of TeX and friends for Windows(even though I believe it can be installed on Linux). It appears at least on the first glance that there is some kind permission problem but I do not know anything about Windows.

Comment: perhaps you don't have "write permission" for the directory/folder you are working in; I would check the Properties tab to begin with. BTW, OS = Operating System.

Comment: I'll assume that you are working on Windows, for your comments. I think that you have to invoke `htlatex` from the command line (the black background window). So, in order to use it you have to open a command window, by typing `cmd` in the same search bar. And then you can type `htlatex C:\path\to\your\file\name.tex`. That will create the HTML for you.

Comment: You may also be able to add htlatex as a compilation option to your LaTeX IDE or text editor.  Whether that is possible, and the way to do it would depend on which IDE or editor are you using.

Comment: I see in your other question that you use TeXWorks.  I have no experience with TeXWorks, but I believe it is fairly configurable, so there should be a way to do it. Perhaps someone more knowledgeable about TeXWorks can help.

Comment: I extend my answer, because I see you are struggling with the command prompt in your other questions. Check if the correction helps.

Comment: On window run the `cmd` console as an administrator, just right click and you will see the menu.

Answer (score 12):

This may help you. I made a [batch script](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file) that I use when working with `htlatex`. You can copy and paste it into a file, and save it with `.bat` extension, e.g., `html.bat`.

1. You need to open a [command prompt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_Prompt), you can type in the search bar `cmd`, or press <kbd>WndLogo + R</kbd> and write `cmd` to execute the command prompt. The command prompt is an application in which you can run different commands. In the top of the window you will see the current directory. For example, `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe`. You can check [this tutorial](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/windows-command-prompt-introduction/) for more information.
2. Then you just need to move to the directory in which you have your file, using `cd path`. For example, if you have your LaTeX documents in a folder in the `C` drive called `My Latex`, you can move to that folder using `cd "C:\My Latex"`. Note that you have to surround the path with quotes due to the spaces on it.
3. You can execute the script using `html.bat file.tex`. That will create a `html` directory in which you can find your file. (This assumes you have your file in the same directory as your `.tex` file. However, you can place the script in a folder and add that folder to your [environment variables](http://vlaurie.com/computers2/Articles/environment.htm). Then you will be able to call it from anywhere.)

   - If you don't want to use the script you can simple execute `htlatex file.tex html "" -dSomeDir "--interaction=nonstopmode"`. The `html` option sets the type of output, `-dSomeDir` sets the output directory to `SomeDir` (although it is not mandatory, it is a good idea as `htlatex` produces several files), and the `nonstopmode` tells the compiler not to stop if it can avoided.

The script looks like this:

```
@echo off
if [%1]==[] goto usage
set name=%~n1
if exist .\html goto exists
mkdir html
goto process
:exists
echo y | del .\html\*
:process

htlatex %name%.tex html "" -dhtml "--interaction=nonstopmode"

:clean
del %name%.4tc > nul
del %name%.4ct > nul
del %name%.tmp > nul
del %name%.xref > nul
del %name%.idv > nul
del %name%.lg > nul
del %name%.html > nul
del %name%.css > nul
goto end

:usage

echo Usage: %0 file.tex
echo *** Caution *** If there is a html directory it will be deleted.
echo. 
:end
```

Comment: It'd be nice if someone could provide a mac-equivalent for this script. That'd be a Unix Shell script.

Comment: I followed your method but I am not getting the references in the output html file. However, it is working fine when I run Latex (using texworks) to compile into pdf. I used the cmd without the batch/script file. also, the non stop interaction is not working, I manually have to hit enter several times for it to proceed

Answer (score 4):

You have to open a command line window.  I do not have an access to a Windows computer at the moment, so I do not know if there is a better way to do it, but I seem to remember that if you click on Start, then navigate to the Programs menu (the way to do it seems to depend on your Windows version), then under Accessories there is something like "DOS Prompt" or "Command Prompt".  When the command prompt window opens, you have to change to the directory (or folder) that contains your file (`cd "\Documents And Something\XYZ's Documents\whatever\folder\it\is\in"`), and run `htlatex myfile.tex`.  That will work if htlatex is in your PATH.  If it is not, you have to type the full path to htlatex instead, something like

```
"C:\the\full path\to\htlatex.exe" myfile.tex
```

Hopefully someone with better knowledge of Windows will be able to edit this or provide a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. Given below are 3 `bat` files, 3 `cfg` files and one `tco` file.
2. Copy *.bat files to 
   `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\tex4ht\` folder.
3. Copy *.cfg files to 
   `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\cfg\` folder.
4. Note that you may have to create `tex4ht` and `cfg` folders.
5. Use MiKTeX Settings(Admin)  and `Refresh FNDB`
6. Go to `TeXnicCenter` -> `Build` -> `Define Output Profiles` -> `Import` `tex4ht.tco`
7. Three (3) new output profiles will be created in `TeXnicCenter`
8. `LaTeX=>HTML2` and `LaTeX=>MathJax` profiles create `*.html` output files:
   `LaTeX=>MathML` profile creates `*.xml` output file.
9. Kindly improve the above by incorporating the code for pstricks and tikz.

`latex2html.bat`

```
REM @echo off
REM - windows batch file for converting latex to html
cd "%1"
htlatex %2 "html,mathml-"
@echo "Process Ended"
```

`latex2mathjax.bat`

```
REM @echo off
REM - windows batch file for converting latex to html using MathJax
cd "%1"
htlatex %2 "ht5mathjax,charset=utf-8,NoFonts" " -cunihtf -utf8"
@echo "Process Ended"
```

`latex2mathml.bat`

```
REM @echo off
REM - windows batch file for converting latex to xml
cd "%1"
mk4ht mzlatex %2 "html,pmathml,charset=utf-8,NoFonts" " -cunihtf -utf8"
@echo "Process Ended"
```

`ht5mathjax.cfg`

```
\Preamble{xhtml,mathml}
\Configure{VERSION}{}
\Configure{DOCTYPE}{\HCode{<!DOCTYPE html>\Hnewline}}
\Configure{HTML}{\HCode{<html>\Hnewline}}{\HCode{\Hnewline</html>}}
\Configure{@HEAD}{}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<meta charset="UTF-8" />\Hnewline}}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<meta name="generator" content="TeX4ht
(http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/\string~gurari/TeX4ht/)" />\Hnewline}}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<link
         rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
         href="\expandafter\csname aa:CssFile\endcsname" />\Hnewline}}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<script type="text/javascript"\Hnewline
src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"\Hnewline
></script>\Hnewline}}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<style type="text/css">\Hnewline
  .MathJax_MathML {text-indent: 0;}\Hnewline
</style>\Hnewline}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble

% From Michal Hoftich <michal.h21@gmail.com> on 2 Aug 2012
% by email with cc to tex4ht@tug.org
% Hoftich suggests the name mathjax.cfg
% His suggested command line:
%   htlatex 1109.1881v2.tex "ht5mathjax, charset=utf-8,NoFonts" " -cunihtf -utf8"
%   to produce html file
% Mods by William F. Hammond
% mk4ht mzlatex $1 "ht5mathjax"
```

`html.cfg`

```
Preamble{xhtml}
\Configure{VERSION}{}
\Configure{DOCTYPE}{\HCode{<!DOCTYPE html>\Hnewline}}
\Configure{HTML}{\HCode{<html>\Hnewline}}{\HCode{\Hnewline</html>}}
\Configure{@HEAD}{}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<meta charset="UTF-8" />\Hnewline}}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<meta name="generator" content="TeX4ht
(http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/\string~gurari/TeX4ht/)" />\Hnewline}}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<link
         rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
         href="\expandafter\csname aa:CssFile\endcsname" />\Hnewline}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

`xhtml.cfg`

```
\Configure{VERSION}{}
\Configure{DOCTYPE}{\HCode{<!DOCTYPE html>\Hnewline}}
\Configure{HTML}{\HCode{<html>\Hnewline}}{\HCode{\Hnewline</html>}}
\Configure{@HEAD}{}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<meta charset="UTF-8" />\Hnewline}}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<meta name="generator" content="TeX4ht
(http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/\string~gurari/TeX4ht/)" />\Hnewline}}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<link
         rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
         href="\expandafter\csname aa:CssFile\endcsname" />\Hnewline}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

`tex4ht.tco`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
<txcop:outputProfiles version="2" xmlns:txcop="http://schemas.ToolsCenter.org/TeXnicCenter/OutputProfiles.xsd">
    <outputProfileList>
        <outputProfile name="LaTeX=&gt;MathJax" stopOnLatexError="false">
            <texCommand execute="false" path="" arguments=""/>
            <bibTexCommand execute="false" path="" arguments=""/>
            <makeIndexCommand execute="false" path="" arguments=""/>
            <preProcessors/>
            <postProcessors>
                <processor name="latex2mathjax" path="latex2mathjax.bat" arguments="&quot;%dm&quot; %nm" inputFile="" outputFile=""/>
            </postProcessors>
            <viewer path="firefox.exe" closeBeforeCompilation="false">
                <viewProjectCommand type="commandLine">
                    <commandLineCommand path="firefox.exe" arguments="%bm.html"/>
                    <ddeCommand path="" server="" topic="System" command=""/>
                </viewProjectCommand>
                <viewCurrentFileCommand type="commandLine">
                    <commandLineCommand path="firefox.exe" arguments=""/>
                    <ddeCommand path="" server="" topic="System" command=""/>
                </viewCurrentFileCommand>
                <viewCloseCommand type="commandLine">
                    <commandLineCommand path="" arguments=""/>
                    <ddeCommand path="" server="" topic="System" command=""/>
                </viewCloseCommand>
            </viewer>
        </outputProfile>
        <outputProfile name="LaTeX=&gt;HTML2" stopOnLatexError="false">
            <texCommand execute="false" path="" arguments=""/>
            <bibTexCommand execute="false" path="" arguments=""/>
            <makeIndexCommand execute="false" path="" arguments=""/>
            <preProcessors/>
            <postProcessors>
                <processor name="latex2html batch file" path="latex2html.bat" arguments="&quot;%dm&quot; %nm" inputFile="" outputFile=""/>
            </postProcessors>
            <viewer path="firefox.exe&quot;" closeBeforeCompilation="false">
                <viewProjectCommand type="commandLine">
                    <commandLineCommand path="firefox.exe&quot;" arguments="%bm.html"/>
                    <ddeCommand path="" server="" topic="System" command=""/>
                </viewProjectCommand>
                <viewCurrentFileCommand type="commandLine">
                    <commandLineCommand path="firefox.exe&quot;" arguments=""/>
                    <ddeCommand path="" server="" topic="System" command=""/>
                </viewCurrentFileCommand>
                <viewCloseCommand type="commandLine">
                    <commandLineCommand path="" arguments=""/>
                    <ddeCommand path="" server="" topic="System" command=""/>
                </viewCloseCommand>
            </viewer>
        </outputProfile>
        <outputProfile name="LaTeX =&gt; MathML" stopOnLatexError="false">
            <texCommand execute="false" path="htlatex.exe " arguments="%bm.tex &quot;html,mathplayer&quot;"/>
            <bibTexCommand execute="false" path="" arguments=""/>
            <makeIndexCommand execute="false" path="" arguments=""/>
            <preProcessors/>
            <postProcessors>
                <processor name="latex2mathml" path="latex2mathml.bat" arguments="&quot;%dm&quot; %nm" inputFile="" outputFile=""/>
            </postProcessors>
            <viewer path="firefox.exe" closeBeforeCompilation="false">
                <viewProjectCommand type="commandLine">
                    <commandLineCommand path="firefox.exe" arguments="%bm.xml"/>
                    <ddeCommand path="" server="" topic="System" command=""/>
                </viewProjectCommand>
                <viewCurrentFileCommand type="commandLine">
                    <commandLineCommand path="firefox.exe" arguments=""/>
                    <ddeCommand path="" server="" topic="System" command=""/>
                </viewCurrentFileCommand>
                <viewCloseCommand type="commandLine">
                    <commandLineCommand path="" arguments=""/>
                    <ddeCommand path="" server="" topic="System" command=""/>
                </viewCloseCommand>
            </viewer>
        </outputProfile>
    </outputProfileList>
</txcop:outputProfiles>
```