# MiKTeX's tex4ht gives:

Tags: tex4ht

I am trying to compile a LaTeX document to HTML using tex4ht, using the MiKTeX's tex4ht and Texmaker. I am trying to do this using a user command:

```
C:\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\tex4ht.exe htlatex %.tex
```

The my file compiles fine to PDF, but using this user command gives the following error:

```
Process started

---------------------------- tex4ht.c (2010-12-16-08:39 Windows MiKTeX) C:\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\tex4ht.exe htlatex helloworld.tex

--- warning --- Can't find/open file `helloworld.dvi' --- error --- Can't find/open file `helloworld.dvi'

Process exited with error(s)
```

The file I am using is a simple Hello World, and is saved as helloworld.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello World!
\end{document}
```

I have looked at [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42927/converting-from-latex-to-html-using-htlatex), which says that it is an error, but a file should have been produced, but I cannot find any output. Also the code suggested there gives me the same problem.

Lastly, I looked at the [tex4ht troubleshooting site](http://tug.org/applications/tex4ht/mn3.html) which says a filter should be installed, but doesn't say how.

Anybody know this problem. Or can tell me how I can use tex4ht on miktex.

EDIT:

Using htlatex directly gives:

```
C:\test>htlatex test.tex

======================================================================
htlatex: Cannot start MiKTeX package manager.
htlatex: Data: Invalid syntax
======================================================================
htlatex: The Windows command script file could not be found.
htlatex: Data: scripts/tex4ht/htlatex.bat
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tex4ht.exe` is postprocesor which takes `dvi` file with `tex4ht` instructions and translate it to the `html` file. you should compile your `tex` file directly with `htlatex` script.

---

**edit:**
if there is no `htlatex.bat` script in `miktex`, you can create new one:

```
latex %5 \makeatletter\def\HCode{\futurelet\HCode\HChar}\def\HChar{\ifx"\HCode\def\HCode"##1"{\Link##1}\expandafter\HCode\else\expandafter\Link\fi}\def\Link#1.a.b.c.{\g@addto@macro\@documentclasshook{\RequirePackage[#1,html]{tex4ht}}\let\HCode\documentstyle\def\documentstyle{\let\documentstyle\HCode\expandafter\def\csname tex4ht\endcsname{#1,html}\def\HCode####1{\documentstyle[tex4ht,}\@ifnextchar[{\HCode}{\documentstyle[tex4ht]}}}\makeatother\HCode %2.a.b.c.\input  %1
latex %5 \makeatletter\def\HCode{\futurelet\HCode\HChar}\def\HChar{\ifx"\HCode\def\HCode"##1"{\Link##1}\expandafter\HCode\else\expandafter\Link\fi}\def\Link#1.a.b.c.{\g@addto@macro\@documentclasshook{\RequirePackage[#1,html]{tex4ht}}\let\HCode\documentstyle\def\documentstyle{\let\documentstyle\HCode\expandafter\def\csname tex4ht\endcsname{#1,html}\def\HCode####1{\documentstyle[tex4ht,}\@ifnextchar[{\HCode}{\documentstyle[tex4ht]}}}\makeatother\HCode %2.a.b.c.\input  %1
latex %5 \makeatletter\def\HCode{\futurelet\HCode\HChar}\def\HChar{\ifx"\HCode\def\HCode"##1"{\Link##1}\expandafter\HCode\else\expandafter\Link\fi}\def\Link#1.a.b.c.{\g@addto@macro\@documentclasshook{\RequirePackage[#1,html]{tex4ht}}\let\HCode\documentstyle\def\documentstyle{\let\documentstyle\HCode\expandafter\def\csname tex4ht\endcsname{#1,html}\def\HCode####1{\documentstyle[tex4ht,}\@ifnextchar[{\HCode}{\documentstyle[tex4ht]}}}\makeatother\HCode %2.a.b.c.\input  %1
tex4ht %1  -i/tex4ht/ht-fonts/%3 -ewin32/tex4ht.env
t4ht %1 %4 -ewin32/tex4ht.env
```

this script is from `texlive`, I hope it will work also with `miktex`

Comment: thanks for your comment, I tried that, I'll add to my question what I got there.

Comment: I mean your answer

Comment: I've put that in C:\MiKTEX\scripts\tex4ht but it gives the same results, using htlatex.bat in the command says it is not a recognised command.

Comment: try to put it in the same directory as your tex file

Comment: Ok I can run the .bat and load the file, now it says tex4ht.sty is not found. Any idea's?

Comment: do you get this error also when you put \usepackage{tex4ht} in your tex file and then compile with latex?

Comment: maybe you have broken instalation of tex4ht, maybe it is miktex bug

Comment: your right, according to this document: http://www.access2science.com/latex/tutorial_txht.xhtml#x1-40001.1, MiKTeX 2.9's tex4ht is broken, using MiKTeX 2.8 does work.