# Setting image size in html output of tex4ht

Tags: graphics, tex4ht, html, dimensions

I have a complex document which I'm trying to convert to `html` with `tex4ht` and TeXLive under Ubuntu, but I'm not able to coherently control the image size of `jpg` and `eps` images. In `html` output, `jpg` images get direct reference to original image and seems to display at 1 to 1 pixel, while `eps` images are converted into a `png` image whose size is specified in `html` but seems to display too small. In both (or at least some) cases the original `\includegraphics[width=mymeasure]{myimage.jpg-eps}` specification isn't respected. I've tried a lot of tricks, configurations and snippets (like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/71498/28685) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21695/28685)) without success.

Is it possible to transfer the size specified for images in LaTeX source to `html` output?

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit:
\begin{centering}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{myimage.jpg}

\includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{myimage.jpg}

\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{myimage.eps}

\includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{myimage.eps}
\end{centering}
\end{document}
```

which I compile with `htlatex myfile`.

And here is the `html` output.

[image]

As you can see, the big (as well as the small) `jpg` and `eps` images should have the same (100%) width, whereas they don't (in `html`, but they do in the `pdf`).

Also, the two `jpg` images should have one the half width of the other, whereas they don't (in `html`, but they do in the `pdf`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: This answer is quite old. Look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/563314/2891) for a more recent information.

---

This works correctly for me with TeX Live 2012 on Linux.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit:    

\begin{centering}
\includegraphics[width=.7\textwidth]{myimage.eps}\\
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{myimage.eps}\\
\includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{myimage.eps}\\
\end{centering}

\the\dimexpr .7\textwidth\relax
\end{document}
```

Resulting html:

```xml
<p class="noindent" ><img 
src="epss0x.png" alt="PIC" class="graphics" width="241.49895pt" height="169.62851pt"  /><!--tex4ht:graphics  
name="epss0x.png" src="myimage.eps"  
--><br />
<img 
src="epss1x.png" alt="PIC" class="graphics" width="103.50105pt" height="72.6991pt"  /><!--tex4ht:graphics  
name="epss1x.png" src="myimage.eps"  
--><br />
<img 
src="epss2x.png" alt="PIC" class="graphics" width="345.0pt" height="242.3276pt"  /><!--tex4ht:graphics  
name="epss2x.png" src="myimage.eps"  
--><br />
</p><!--l. 13--><p class="indent" >   241.49895pt</p>
```

Note that `width=.7\textwidth` and `\the\dimexpr .7\textwidth\relax` are producing the same value: `241.49895pt`.

[image]

Regarding `jpg` images, dimension information isn't saved for some reason. But we can use custom config file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Configure{graphics*}
        {jpg}
        {%  
           \Picture[pict]{\csname Gin@base\endcsname .jpg
              \space width="\the\dimexpr \expandafter\csname Gin@req@width\endcsname * 1.5"
}%  
         }
\Configure{graphics*}
        {png}
        {%  
           \Picture[pict]{\csname Gin@base\endcsname .png
              \space width="\expandafter\the\csname Gin@req@width\endcsname"
}%  
         }
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

This will increase seze of the included image by factor os `1.5`. Save it as `myconf.cfg` and compile the source file with

```
htlatex myfile myconf
```

Comment: Thanks for your right observation, it helped me to better focus the problem, which remains. See the question I updated accordingly.

Comment: It worked, thanks! Adding your config snippet and compiling with it, `jpg` images resized accordingly to `eps` images, so I guess there no `eps` bounding box issue. Only one detail: adding config code for `png` as you said, a strange line ('png pict') shows up at beginning of `html`. Maybe it's because I don't actually have any `png` image? (but I will in real document) Could you add `png` to your config code to make sure I used the right code? (and that you don't have such issue)

Comment: @mmj I edeted the config file to show  the `png` configuration

Comment: Thanks, I did not duplicate the `\Configure{graphics*}` row. No doubt you brilliantly solved this problem, nonetheless the `1.0\textwidth` image width is smaller than I wish, when I compare it with font size, in `html` output. Is there a way to tell `tex4ht` to scale all images by a factor?

Comment: @mmj you can try to use make4ht image conversion (https://github.com/michal-h21/make4ht#image-conversion) and specify output resolution for dvipng (with `-D` option)

Comment: The link you suggested me is too advanced for my knowledge, I'd need a 'make4ht for dummies' version. But I made some experiments and I understood that, in the config file, `Gin@req@width` is the width that appears in `html` output. Isn't there a way to manipulate that value so that it can be multiplied by a factor?

Comment: Unfortunately the hack you added does not work, at least for me. The `html` output is affected (`<img width="172.5pt* 1.5" alt="pict" src="myimage.jpg"></img>`), but visualization is not, I guess because the multiplication is simply ignored.

Answer (score 0):

(not enough reputation to comment, so I am making an answer)

As mmj said in his comment, the multiplication does not work, at least for us, and only integers will work that way (decimal point not recognized?). Writing 4.523 will multiply by 4.

**Putting the 1.5 factor in the middle works** for me as expected:

```latex
          \space width="\the\dimexpr 1.5 \expandafter\csname Gin@req@width\endcsname"
```