# Global scaling of images in html output (only) of htlatex

Tags: graphics, scaling, tex4ht, html

I have the following MWE with some images:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit:

\begin{centering}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{myimage.jpg}
\includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{myimage.jpg}
\end{centering}
\end{document}
```

which compile as expected with `pdflatex myfile.tex` to `pdf` output, with one image half of the text width and the other same width as text. Then, using the following config file (needed to obtain images with correct relative sizes):

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Configure{graphics*}
    {jpg}
    {\Picture[pict]{\csname Gin@base\endcsname .jpg
        \space width="\expandafter\the\csname Gin@req@width\endcsname"}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

I compile the same source with `htlatex myfile myconfig`, in order to obtain an `html` version of my document. Image sizes are correct among themselves, but they are too small compared to text size. I guess this has something to do with the fact that `html` has not a fixed page width, so `tex4ht` has to choose a value to be used has 'page width', and such value is too small, at least for me.

Is there a 'TeX way' to scale all images in `html` output by a factor?

Of course I could increase the width of images in my `latex` source, but that would be time consuming and would affect `pdf` too, which is undesiderable.

Or I could write some external script to parse `html` output and manipulate image sizes in `html` source, but I'd prefer a TeX-confined solution.

Someone might like to be informed that the present question arised from [this other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/148173/28685).

**UPDATE**

Given that many days have passed with no answers, I'll open the question to answers which are not TeX-confined. See below for a possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

Adopting the external script workaround, [other issues](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/151192/28685) arised, which luckily found a [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/151497/28685). Basically you have to use a configuration file able to take care of all the image format you have. Here is `myconfig.cfg` updated in order to take care of `jpg`, `png` and `eps` image formats:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Configure{graphics*}
    {jpg}
    {\Picture[pict]{\csname Gin@base\endcsname.jpg
        \space width="\expandafter\the\csname Gin@req@width\endcsname"}}
\Configure{graphics*}
    {png}
    {\Picture[pict]{\csname Gin@base\endcsname.png
        \space width="\expandafter\the\csname Gin@req@width\endcsname"}}
\Configure{graphics*}
    {eps}
    {\Needs{"convert -density 110x110 \csname Gin@base\endcsname.eps \csname Gin@base\endcsname.png"}
    \Picture[pict]{\csname Gin@base\endcsname.png
        \space width="\expandafter\the\csname Gin@req@width\endcsname"}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

And here is my post-production Python script able to multiply by a factor `width` and `height` attributes of images in `html` source:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# usage under Ubuntu 12.04 with Python 3.2: python3 fixhtml.py my_html
# requirement: my_html file is expected to be UTF-8 encoded text file

import sys,re
import os.path

if len(sys.argv)!=2:
    print("You need to specify the HTML file you want to process when you call 'fixhtml'. Try again.")
    sys.exit()
fn=sys.argv[1]
if not os.path.exists(fn):
    print("The file you specified ('"+fn+"')was not found.")
    sys.exit()

print("Processing HTML file '"+fn+"'...")
f=open(fn,'r',encoding="utf-8")
htmltext=f.read()
f.close()

def fixall(text,searchpatt,subpatt,factor,factor_group):
    m=re.search(searchpatt,text)
    fixed_text=''
    while m:
        value=m.group(factor_group)
        new_value=factor*float(value)
        fixed_text+=re.sub(searchpatt,subpatt%new_value,text[:m.end()])
        text=text[m.end():]
        m=re.search(searchpatt,text)
    return fixed_text+text

factor=2.0 # images enlargement factor
factor_group=2 # factor is found in second group of regex search expression
htmltext=fixall(htmltext,'(?ms)img(.+?)width.*?=.*?"([^"a-zA_Z]+)([a-z]{1,3})"',r'img\1width="%.4f\3"',factor,factor_group) # change the last 3 arguments to suit your needs
htmltext=fixall(htmltext,'(?ms)img(.+?)height.*?=.*?"([^"a-zA_Z]+)([a-z]{1,3})"',r'img\1height="%.4f\3"',factor,factor_group) # each line one passage: add as many you want

import codecs
f = codecs.open("fixed_"+fn,'w',encoding='utf8') # output file name is the same as input with the prefix 'fixed_', file is overwritten if existing
f.write(htmltext)
f.close()
```