# tex4ht, html output: increase eps image resolution without affecting math images size

Tags: math-mode, graphics, eps, tex4ht, resolution

I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \(k_\delta=\frac{3 \mathit{EJ}}{l^3}\) consectetur:
\begin{equation*}k_\delta=\frac{3 \mathit{EJ}}{l^3}\end{equation*}

\begin{centering}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{myimage.eps}
\end{centering}
\end{document}
```

which compiles fine to `html` (with `htlatex example.tex "myconfig, xhtml, charset=utf-8" " -cunihtf -utf8"` under Ubuntu TeXLive), `myconfig.cfg` being

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Configure{graphics*}
    {jpg}
    {\Picture[pict]{\csname Gin@base\endcsname .jpg
        \space width="\expandafter\the\csname Gin@req@width\endcsname"}}
\Configure{graphics*}
    {png}
    {\Picture[pict]{\csname Gin@base\endcsname .png
        \space width="\expandafter\the\csname Gin@req@width\endcsname"}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

Looking for a workaround to the [unsolved problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/149679/28685) of small image sizes in `html` output, I wrote a Python script which parses `html` source and doubles `width` and `height` of all images, getting in face of a new problem, poor quality of 'doubled' `eps` images. So I tried to increase density from 110x110 to 220x220 in `tex4ht.env`, `<convert>` section:

```
Gconvert -trim +repage -density 220x220 -transparent '#FFFFFF' zz%%4.ps %%3
```

This actually increased the resolution of `eps` images, so that now I can double their size in `html` source with my Python script, but also increased the *size* of math formula images (whose size is not affected by my Python script because they don't hold `width` nor `height` attributes).

Is there a way to increase `eps` images resolution without affecting math images size?

Here is a screenshot of the `html` output with doubled size of math formulas:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems I managed to find a solution by myself. I rolled back the change to `tex4ht.env`, so that math formulas rendered as image are safe now, and I added the following section to my above mentioned preamble `myconfig.cfg`:

```
\Configure{graphics*}
    {eps}
    {\Needs{"convert -density 110x110 \csname Gin@base\endcsname.eps \csname Gin@base\endcsname.png"}
    \Picture[pict]{\csname Gin@base\endcsname.png}}
```

This way `eps` images are managed in a different way (`dvi` code is bypassed, as said [here](http://www.tug.org/applications/tex4ht/mn3.html#QQ1-3-4)), so that now they lack `width` attribute in `html` source; however such lack is perfectly fine because now `eps` images look bigger in `html` output, their size is satisfactory and they don't need to be "externally" enlarged through my post-production Python script.

Here is a screenshot of original example after solution:

[image]

**FOLLOW UP**

I actually discovered that, although above solution is able to enlarge `eps` images, their size is independent from the size specified in LaTeX source, and inconsistent with `jpg` and `png` images, which retain the `width`
and `height` in `html` output. If you are looking for a *consistent* solution, the `eps` section of `myconfig.cfg` should be

```
\Configure{graphics*}
    {eps}
    {\Needs{"convert -density 110x110 \csname Gin@base\endcsname.eps \csname Gin@base\endcsname.png"}
    \Picture[pict]{\csname Gin@base\endcsname.png
        \space width="\expandafter\the\csname Gin@req@width\endcsname"}}
```

This way `width` and `height` attributes in `html` output are retained also for `eps` images, and their size is consistent with `jpg` and `png` images, as I describe also in the [problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/149679/28685) I cited before.

Comment: Why not just use the geometry option as in: `Gconvert -trim +repage -density 220 -geometry 50% -transparent '#FFFFFF' zz%%4.ps %%3`  or the resample option as in `Gconvert -trim +repage -density 220 -resample 120 -transparent '#FFFFFF'` zz%%4.ps %%3`

Comment: I tried your code but they did not work, at least for me.

Comment: No problem. It works for me just fine. `Gconvert -trim +repage -density 220 -geometry 50% -transparent '#FFFFFF' zz%%4.ps %%3` is also documented here http://tug.org/applications/tex4ht/mn3.html  "Increase the density (number of dots per inch) when converting the pictures, and then sub-sample the picture."