# How do I improve the quality of png images when converting to html using htlatex?

Tags: math-mode, htlatex, png

I have tried to convert my LaTeX document into xhtml running the following commands (found [here](http://therandymon.com/index.php?/150-Making-an-EPUB-from-LaTeX.html)):

```
htlatex source.tex

tidy -asxhtml -output seconddraft.xhtml firstdraft.html
```

Everything displays perfectly, except the math formulas are rendered as very poor quality `png` images. Is there a way to improve the resolution (or to generate another image format such as `svg`)?

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/225136/2891

Comment: Please see: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151192/tex4ht-html-output-increase-eps-image-resolution-without-affecting-math-images

Comment: If I read correctly, this [question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/228919/34551) gives a (seemingly involved) way to output `svg` with `htlatex`.