# tex4ebook generating `width=289` instead of `width="100%"` for \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{}

Tags: tex4ebook

In my MWE I specify the image rendering to be `width=\textwidth`. I generate the epub/html with `tex4ebook main.tex`. The generated html for the image sets `width=289` and `height=289` (even tho I didn't specify a height) which doesn't render well on some eReaders. If I edit the html and delete the height and specify `width='100%'` it renders perfectly on the couple eReaders I tested on.

Is there a reason width shouldn't be a percentage? If not, is there a way to tell tex4ebook to render at 100% (or any percentage)?

```
\documentclass[ebook]{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/ebook} }

\begin{document}
Here's a png:\\
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{chapter_ornament.png}
\end{document}
```

Here's the generated html with width and height set to 289 (instead of 100%)

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd"><html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'> 
<head><title></title> 
<meta content='text/html; charset=utf-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' /> 
<meta content='TeX4ht (https://tug.org/tex4ht/)' name='generator' /> 
<meta content='TeX4ht (https://tug.org/tex4ht/)' name='originator' /> 
<!--  xhtml,charset=utf-8,epub,uni-html4,html  --> 
<meta content='main.tex' name='src' /> 
<link href='main.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' /> 
</head><body>
<!-- l. 6 --><p class='noindent'>Here’s a png:<br class='newline' /><img alt='PIC' height='289' src='./images/ebook/chapter_ornament.jpg' width='289' />
</p>      
</body></html>
```

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/563314/2891

Comment: Thanks @michal.h21! It is a duplicate, but its solution isn't working me. Per the solution, I added `\Configure{Gin-percent}` to my `tex4ebook.cfg` and ran `tex4ebook -l -c tex4ebook.cfg main.tex` and my `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{chapter_ornament.png}` line still generates a width and height of 289. I'm running TeX Live 2023 and my packages are update to date.

Comment: It shouldn't be `\Configure{Gin-perecent}`, but `\Preamble{xhtml,Gin-percent}`. Or use the config file itself, because I found that `Gin-percent` may not work as you would expect (it uses `max-width` instead of `width` CSS property).

Comment: Awesome. Worked great. Thanks @michal.h21!!!