# How to Convert XeTeX to HTML

Tags: conversion, html

I realize its too much to post the entire document. Here is a small portion of document, it just keep repeating itself for various verses. Sorry this is the minimum example size I could squeeze it to.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
%\usepackage[left=0.15in,right=0.15in,top=0.75in,bottom=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\AtBeginEnvironment{Verse}{\singlespacing}

\AtBeginEnvironment{longtable}{\onehalfspacing}

\newcommand{\blt}{\begin{longtable}{p{1.5cm}p{0.05cm}p{3.5cm}|p{1.5cm}p{0.05cm}p{3.5cm}|p{1.5cm}p{0.05cm}p{3.5cm}}}
\newcommand{\elt}{\end{longtable}}

\newcommand{\bv}{\begin{Verse}\large}
\newcommand{\ev}{\end{Verse}}

\newcommand{\bfns}{\begin{footnotesize}}
\newcommand{\efns}{\end{footnotesize}}

\newcommand{\sz}{\\[\normalbaselineskip]}
\newcommand{\csec}[1]{\section{#1}}

\newenvironment{Verse}
  {\center\varwidth{\linewidth}}
  {\endvarwidth\endcenter}

\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari]{Sanskrit 2003}

\begin{document} 
\bv
तपः स्वाध्यायनिरताम् तपस्वी वाग्विदाम् वरम् |          \\ 
नारदम् परिपप्रच्छ वाल्मीकिर्मुनिपुङ्गवम् ॥ १.१.१ ॥
\ev

\bfns  \blt \hline
तपस्वी & = &  sagacious thinker & वाल्मीकि: & = &  Sage [Poet]  वाल्मीकि & तपः & = & in thoughtful-meditation  \\
स्व अध्याय & = & in self, study of scriptures & निरतम् & = & always - who is eternally studious in scriptures& वाक् & = & in speaking [in enunciation] \\

विदाम् & = & among expert enunciators & वरम् & = & sublime one - with नारद & मुनि पुन्गवम् & = & with sage, paragon, with such a paragon sage Naarada \\

नारदम्  & = &  with [such a sage] Naarada & परिपप्रच्छ  & = &  verily [inquisitively,] inquired about

\elt \efns

सर्व गुण समिष्टि रूपम् पुरुषम्  all, merited endowments, composite, in form - about such a man.] 
A thoughtful-meditator, an eternally studious sage in scriptures about the Truth and Untruth, a sagacious thinker, and a sublime enunciator among all expert enunciators is नारद, and with such a Divine Sage नारद, the Sage-Poet वाल्मीकि is inquisitively enquiring about a man who is a composite for all merited endowments in his form and calibre. [1-1-1]\\  
\end{document}
```

This is the command I ran: `htxelatex bala.tex # generate html`. Now I am getting the following error:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-math.4ht))
(./bala.aux)

! LaTeX Error: Command `\acute' already defined in `'.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.33 \begin{document}

?
```

I changed the package options of `fontspec` to `\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}` and it gave me this error:

```
----------------------------------------------------
(--- xdv font = [/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmmono10-regular.otf] (not implemented) ---)
--- warning --- Couldn't find font `[/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmmono10-regular.otf].htf' (char codes: 0--255)
(--- xdv font = Sanskrit2003 (not implemented) ---)
--- warning --- Couldn't find font `Sanskrit2003.htf' (char codes: 0--255)
(--- xdv font = Sanskrit2003 (not implemented) ---)
--- error --- Illegal storage address
----------------------------

t4ht.c (2010-12-16-08:47 kpathsea)
t4ht -.xdv 
  -f/Bala 
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex4ht/base/unix/tex4ht.env)
Entering Bala.lg
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using htlatex to convert LaTeX to HTML](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39444/using-htlatex-to-convert-latex-to-html)

Comment: I can get your code to compile without errors using `htxelatex` and if I comment out fontspec, hyperref, multicol and inputenc, but Indic characters don't appear. I think you should consult this problem at tex4ht mailing list  http://tug.org/mailman/listinfo/tex4ht

Comment: Actually if you make the question a bit more specific, e.g. how to convert a `XeLaTeX` document to HTML this may not end up as a duplicate.

Comment: One thing about your xelatex source: you should *never* load the `inputenc` package with xelatex documents. Also, rather than posting a link to a huge document, you should try to make a simple example first to see where things are breaking.

Comment: @AlanMunn- I created XeLaTeX document first, learning LaTeX along the way, which gave a nice pdf output. Exactly that way I wanted. After that I realized it would be nice if I can convert this to html so that I could post it on the webpage. Thats how I got into trouble. just to give you an idea the total pdf pages in the document are over 7000. really dont want to rewrite the entire document again.

Comment: @Aku nobody is asking you to write the whole document again, but to discover where the problem lies, you can't start with a 7000 page document.  You first need to make some very small test documents, work with `htxelatex` and then go from there.

Comment: @AlanMunn - I created a small example, should I paste it in the question to see if people here can help me out with the solution or should I post a new question.

Comment: @Aku That's good. I think it's fine to edit your question here rather than post a new question.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44236/2036

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I know that you finally have found a solution, but there is solution for `tex4ht`, if anybody is interested.

There are three problems:

1. You run `htxelatex bala.tex # generate html` - there should be not `# generate html`, this is just some comment. Correct command is `htlatex bala.tex "xhtml, charset=utf-8" " -cunihtf -utf8"` in the case of unicode input. It seems that support for xetex is limited, so it's best to run `htlatex` and not `htxelatex`!
2. `tex4ht` is incompatible with some xelatex packages, in this case `xlxtra, fontspec and polyglossia`, so you must edit your preamble to not include them if `tex4ht` is running.
3. This problem is most interesting - if you run your file either with `htlatex, htxelatex` or `htlualatex`, the `devanagari` characters are missing - I don't know the right solution, but you can use `inputenc's` `DeclareUnicodeCharacter` to enter directly `character codes` with the help of `tex4ht` macro `\HChar`:

   ```
   \DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0904}{\HChar{224}\HChar{164}\HChar{132}} % ऄ
   ```

   You can find all codes in file [devng4ht.sty](https://gist.github.com/1816936)

So now your preamble should look like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{tex4ht}{
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{devng4ht}
}{%
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari]{Sanskrit 2003}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
}

\newcommand{\bv}{\begin{Verse}}
\newcommand{\ev}{\end{Verse}}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\AtBeginEnvironment{Verse}{\singlespacing}

\AtBeginEnvironment{longtable}{\onehalfspacing}

\newcommand{\blt}{\begin{longtable}{p{1.5cm}p{0.05cm}p{3.5cm}|p{1.5cm}p{0.05cm}p{3.5cm}|p{1.5cm}p{0.05cm}p{3.5cm}}}
\newcommand{\elt}{\end{longtable}}

\newcommand{\bfns}{\begin{footnotesize}}
\newcommand{\efns}{\end{footnotesize}}

\newcommand{\sz}{\\[\normalbaselineskip]}
\newcommand{\csec}[1]{\section{#1}}

\newenvironment{Verse}
  {\center\varwidth{\linewidth}}
  {\endvarwidth\endcenter}
```

There is some limitation - you cannot use fot changing switches like `large` or `\footnotesize` - from some reason, they will break correct rendering of devanagari.

But you can use private configuration file to adjust your macros using `html` tags and `css` codes. File `devng.cfg`:

```
\Preamble{xhtml, charset=utf-8}
\Css{
  .verse{
    font-size:large;
    margin:2em;
    width:auto;
  }
  .bfns{
    font-size:small;
  }
}
\begin{document}
\let\old@bv\bv
\renewcommand\bv{\leavevmode\EndP\NoFonts\HtmlParOff\HCode{\Hnewline<div class="verse">\Hnewline}\old@bv}
\let\old@ev\ev
\renewcommand\ev{\NoFonts\HCode{\Hnewline</div>\Hnewline}\old@ev\HtmlParOn\EndNoFonts}
\let\old@bfns\bfns
\renewcommand\bfns{\leavevmode\SaveEndP\NoFonts\Tg<div class="bfns">\old@bfns}
\let\old@efns\efns
\renewcommand\efns{\NoFonts\Tg</div>\old@efns\EndNoFonts}
\EndPreamble
```

I use `\NoFonts` to suppress processing of character codes which causes disappearing of devanagari characters. Now you can finally compile your file:

```
htlatex bala.tex devng " -cunihtf -utf8"
```

[image: devnagari sample]

Comment: Michal.h21 - Awesome!!, I don't have words to express my gratitude. This is exactly what I need. May God bless you.

Comment: your answer is very helpful, but normally pdflatex, which is used by htlatex, cannot recognize unicode and stop at ``undefined control sequence''.

Comment: @zsf222 this answer is a little bit outdated by now, `tex4ht` now supports `Fontspec`. You need to use lualatex or xelatex, which aren't supported by `htlatex`, use `make4ht -l` or `make4ht -x` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try [TeX4ht](http://tug.org/applications/tex4ht/mn.html). It seems to be the best solution till now.

Comment: When I tried this "htlatex  filename  # generate HTML" I am getting lot of errors. The thing is I don't have much of computer background to make sense, so I was looking for a working example so that I can learn from that.

Comment: It is hard tou use LaTeX without a computer background. Anyway: do you work on linux? have you installed TeXLive? If yes, open a terminal, navigate to the folder with Bala.tex and 001.tex, then type `htxelatex Bala.tex`. Let me know the output of the terminal. If you work on windows, sorry I cannot help.

Comment: Here is the error
*geometry* detected driver: xetex
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ucs/ucsencs.def)
*** you should *not* be loading the inputenc package
*** XeTeX expects the source to be in UTF8 encoding
*** some features of other encodings may conflict, resulting in poor output.

! LaTeX Error: Command `\acute' already defined in `'.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.58 \begin{document}

Comment: Sam - ran this command "htxelatex Bala.tex # generate html" to get below error
(--- xdv font = Sanskrit2003 (not implemented) ---)
--- warning --- Couldn't find font `Sanskrit2003.htf' (char codes: 0--255)
[1 file Bala.html
 file Bala.css
 file Bala.tmp
]
 ===> ------ xdv's idv --------- <====  253
 ===> ---------- xdv's idv ------------ <====  253
--- error --- Implementation problem
----------------------------
t4ht.c (2010-12-16-08:47 kpathsea)
t4ht -.xdv 
  -f/Bala.tex 
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex4ht/base/unix/tex4ht.env)
Entering Bala.lg
Entering Bala.css
Entering Bala.tmp

Answer (score 0):

`pandoc` works well, and is fast in my experience, too

```
pandoc -s foo.tex -o foo.html
```

https://pandoc.org/