# Pandoc - Convert XeTeX to HTML

Tags: xetex, conversion, html, pandoc

I posted the question here [How to Convert XeTeX to HTML](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42933/how-to-convert-xetex-to-html)
However I tried something different so decided to ask the issues with the results as a new question. 
So far my XeTeX file is nicely getting concerted to HTML, thats nice :) I am attaching screenshot of PDF and HTML file. the table format did not come at all in the HTML.

Image one is HTML and image 2 is pdf output. 
minimum example can be found of the previous post link given above.

[image]

[image]

This is the command I ran `pandoc --from latex 001.tex --to html --standalone --output 001.html`

I hope its something in my code than latex limitations. I would greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a Pandoc solution however I thought to post here
With the help of John Macfarlane I got a workable solution. He suggested me to try "hevea" 
For that I had to download `hevea` from this site - ftp://ftp.inria.fr/INRIA/Projects/para/hevea/

Download `Ocaml` http://caml.inria.fr/ocaml/ and install.

cd to hevea directory and follow the installation procedure. 
Then use this command. `hevea <filename.tex>`

There you go, you should have a html file with tables. However here is something latex gurus can help figure out. 
[image]

As can be seen on the original image there were only three vertical lines but now it seems each cell has a border. can this border be change to match with original pdf formatting.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42933/how-to-convert-xetex-to-html/44396#44396

Answer (score 5):

Pandoc's LaTeX parser is limited; it will generally get you most of the way there, but some manual cleanup is usually required.  Note also that  pandoc currently interprets LaTeX macros only in math contexts, and your document makes heavy use of macros.

Comment: so in short at the point there is no easy solution for the problem I got myself into. :(, When you said manual cleanup is required then can you please elaborate on that part.