# Converting Doc file with wsW2LTX 1.1 GUI

Tags: unicode, word-to-latex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting MS Word .doc to LaTeX by command line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46015/converting-ms-word-doc-to-latex-by-command-line)

I want convert a word file to .tex (XeTeX) with [wsW2LTX](http://www.winshell.org/modules/w2ltx_download/) 1.1 GUI
But converted file is full of unknown numerical code like [24542] for non-latin alphabit. Is ther any solution?

Is there any better library for converting .doc to tex?

outbut sample:

```
\begin{itemize}

\item

\textbf{[62d][631][648][641] }\textbf{}

\end{itemize}

[627][6cc][646] [62e][637] [627][632] 27 [62d][631][641] [62a][634][6a9][6cc][644] [645][6cc][200c][634][648][62f].


\begin{longtable}{*{5}{p{20.46\wvtextpercent}}}
\hline
```

Comment: See some of the solutions here: [Converting MS Word .doc to LaTeX by command line](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46015/2693).  I've had good success with [`rtf2latex2e`](http://rtf2latex2e.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: @AlanMunn I got following message with proposed program:

Processing x.rtf
ReadFontTbl: unknown token "\flomajor"
ReadFontTbl: unknown token "\fdbmajor" ....

Comment: If you want help with `rtf2latex2e` you should ask another question, or edit your question to reflect that. Also, without a sample of your input RTF file, it would be very hard to diagnose the problem.

Comment: @AlanMunn Thanks Alan, I switched to writer2latex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using writer (either from openoffice or LibreOffice), then you can use the new beta version of writer2latex which supports XeTeX. See [Here](http://extensions.libreoffice.org/extension-center/writer2latex-1/releases/1.2) for more details.