# .doc -> latex preserving font

Tags: conversion

This is a follow-up to [Converting MS Word .doc to LaTeX by command line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46015/converting-ms-word-doc-to-latex-by-command-line).

Do any of those utilities, or any others, have a mechanism to preserve the *font* when converting from `.doc` to tex?  I'm dealing with a document in which source code is indicated by Courier font, and all of the approaches I've attempted (e.g., textutils -> html -> pandoc) preserve some of the formatting but ignore the font.  I've found no clear way to pull out source code by other means (e.g., regexp).

Comment: If you are willing to use `xetex` or `luatex` as the engines, any system font should be available to you for the converted project.  I've only done .doc to .tex conversions once or twice (many years ago), but I found then that post-processing was sorely needed!  Won't this be the case for your documents as well?  In that case, I'd add 'setting the font' to the list of things that will need some extra attention.

Comment: That's true, post-processing is needed.  I've gone the route of writing my own python script to parse the textutils-created html file into my style of tex.  Line breaks are the current headache...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how it will work, as a large majority of the fonts in Word will not be available in LaTeX. I would probably try to export the Word document, if per chance it was correctly formatted, to XML. Converting the XML to any other markup format should be a much easier task.

Comment: I've exported to html and rtf with no problem - both formats preserve font.  I don't actually care about the font being preserved exactly, but SOME markup indicating a different font is essential.

Comment: Wouldn't HTML use pre or code?

Comment: You'd think so, but no: it uses `<span>` with a css class definition and `font: 12.0px 'Courier New';`

Comment: I knew Word HTML was messy, but not to this point.... In any case, there you go, you can easily parse the HTML to replace any span with these attributes by a code block.

Comment: Note that all fonts available to Word are easily accessible using either `LuaLaTeX` or `XeLaTeX`.