# convert (xe)latex with non-english character to html

Tags: xetex, tex4ht, linux, htlatex

I have an exact problem as [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42933/how-to-convert-xetex-to-html). I have checked the answers there, and found a probable reply [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39444/using-htlatex-to-convert-latex-to-html). Sad that I am in `linux`, and cannot use `bat` file.

Pasted is my `latex` file, which compiles well with `xelatex`:

```
\documentclass[dvipdfmx]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[pass,paperwidth=4in,paperheight=4in]{geometry}
%
%\font\serif="FreeSerif:script=beng"
\font\serifbb="SolaimanLipi:script=beng" at 16pt%
\font\deffont="Lohit-Bengali:script=beng" at 14pt%
%
\author{\serifbb {শক্তি চট্টোপাধ্যায়}}%
\title{\serifbb {যখন বৃষ্টি নামলো}}%
\date{}

\begin{document}
\deffont %Default font used for the document
\maketitle
\noindent
\begin{center}বুকের মধ্যে বৃষ্টি নামে নৌকা টলোমলো\\
কূল ছেড়ে আজ অকূলে যাই এমনও সম্বল\\
নেই নিকটে - হয়ত ছিল বৃষ্টি আসার আগে\\
চলচ্ছক্তিহীন হয়েছি, তাই কি মনে জাগে\\
পোড়োবাড়ির স্মৃতি? আমার স্বপ্নে মেশা দিন\\
চলচ্ছক্তিহীন হয়েছি, চলচ্ছক্তিহীন।
‌\vspace{.5in}\\
বৃষ্টি নামলো যখন আমি উঠোন-পানে একা,\\
দৌড়ে গিয়ে ভেবেছিলাম তোমার পাব দেখা।\\
হয়ত মেঘে-বৃষ্টিতে বা শিউলিগাছের তলে\\
আজানুকেশ ভিজিয়ে নিচ্ছো আকাশ-ছেঁচা জলে\\
কিন্তু তুমি নেই বাহিরে – অন্তরে মেঘ করে,\\
ভারি ব্যাপক বৃষ্টি আমার বুকের মধ্যে ঝরে!\end{center}
\end{document}
```

using xelatex, its working properly:

```
$ xelatex jbn.tex
...
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: xetex
[1] (./jbn.aux) )
Output written on jbn.pdf (1 page).
Transcript written on jbn.log.
```

I tried using htxelatex:

```
$htxelatex trial.tex html
...
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-math.4ht)) (./jbn.aux)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tipa/t3cmr.fd)

! LaTeX Error: Command `\acute' already defined in `'.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.13 \begin{document}

?
```

and then starts printing many things ending up with:

```
 [-S<image-script>]
   [-s<css-file-ext>]   default: -s4cs; multiple entries allowed
   [-t<tfm-font-dir>]
   [-u10]               base 10 for unicode characters
   [-utf8]              utf-8 encoding for unicode characters
   [-v<idv version>]    replacement for the given dvi version
   [-xs]           ms-dos file names for automatically generated gifs
/usr/bin/t4ht: fork: retry: No child processes
/usr/bin/t4ht: fork: retry: No child processes
/usr/bin/t4ht: fork: retry: No child processes
/usr/bin/t4ht: fork: retry: No child processes
/usr/bin/t4ht: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

May I get some help?

**EDIT**
Friends,

I have solved the ``` ! LaTeX Error: Command ``\acute' already defined in ```'. problem by putting `\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}`

but, no child process error is still there, and also, html's body is essentially empty:
html output:

```
<html > 
<head><title>  </title> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"> 
<meta name="generator" content="TeX4ht (http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~gurari/TeX4ht/)"> 
<meta name="originator" content="TeX4ht (http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~gurari/TeX4ht/)"> 
<!-- html --> 
<meta name="src" content="jbn.tex"> 
<meta name="date" content="2013-09-23 18:48:00"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jbn.css"> 
</head><body 
>
   <div class="maketitle">



<h2 class="titleHead">  </h2>
<div class="author" > </div>
<br />
<div class="date" ></div>
   </div>
<div class="center" 
>
<!--l. 17--><p class="noindent" >
<!--l. 17--><p class="noindent" >     <br />
      <br />
       <br />
     <br />
     <br />
   <br />
     <br />
     <br />
    <br />
    <br />
       <br />
      </div>

</body></html>
```

**Make4ht** getting error:

```
~/Downloads/make4ht/make4ht -u -c config -x jbn.tex 
/home/rudra/Downloads/make4ht/make4ht:11: module 'make4ht-lib' not found:
    no field package.preload['make4ht-lib']
    [kpse lua searcher] file not found: 'make4ht-lib'
    [kpse C searcher] file not found: 'make4ht-lib'
```

**After 2nd comment **

I have added the path, as per your instruction and [this link](http://12000.org/my_notes/faq/LATEX/htsu11.htm).

```
 $kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME
/home/rudra/texmf
$ echo $PATH
/home/rudra/texmf/scripts/lua/make4ht:
```

but I am still getting the same error:

```
$ make4ht -u -c config.cfg jbn.tex
tex4ht.c (2012-07-25-19:36 kpathsea)
tex4ht 
--- error --- improper command line
tex4ht [-f<path-separator-ch>]in-file[.dvi]
   [-.<ext>]            replacement to default file extension name .dvi
   [-c<tag name>]       choose named segment in env file
   [-e<env-file>]
   [-f<path-separator-ch>]        remove path from the file name
   [-F<ch-code>]        replacement for missing font characters; 0--255; default 0
   [-g<bitmap-file-ext>]
   [-h(e|f|F|g|s|v|V)]  trace: e-errors/warnings, f-htf, F-htf search
                            g-groups, s-specials, v-env, V-env search
   [-i<htf-font-dir>]
   [-l<bookkeeping-file>]
   [-P(*|<filter>)]     permission for system calls: *-always, filter
   [-S<image-script>]
   [-s<css-file-ext>]   default: -s4cs; multiple entries allowed
   [-t<tfm-font-dir>]
   [-u10]               base 10 for unicode characters
   [-utf8]              utf-8 encoding for unicode characters
   [-v<idv version>]    replacement for the given dvi version
   [-xs]           ms-dos file names for automatically generated gifs
/usr/bin/t4ht: fork: retry: No child processes
/usr/bin/t4ht: fork: retry: No child processes
/usr/bin/t4ht: fork: retry: No child processes
/usr/bin/t4ht: fork: retry: No child processes
/usr/bin/t4ht: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
Parse LG
parse_lg process file: jbn.html
outdir: 
parse_lg process file: jbn.css
outdir: 
parse_lg process file: jbn.tmp
tmp file
```

Comment: you must install make4ht to your local <a href="https://github.com/michal-h21/make4ht#instalation">texmf tree</a>

Comment: you need to use either `-x` or `-l` option to compile your document with xelatex or lualatex. But that error message is strange anyway, could you post your whole compilation log, please?

Answer (score 5):

You may try experimental fontspec [support for tex4ht](https://github.com/michal-h21/fontspec). There is also some [documentation](http://michal-h21.github.io/fontspec/fontspec-4ht.html). I just added support for bengali language.

With some modifications to your source file:

```
\documentclass[dvipdfmx]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[pass,paperwidth=4in,paperheight=4in]{geometry}
%
%\font\serif="FreeSerif:script=beng"
%\font\serifbb="SolaimanLipi:script=beng" at 16pt%
%\font\deffont="Lohit-Bengali:script=beng" at 14pt%
\newfontfamily\serifbb[Script=Bengali]{SolaimanLipi}
\newfontfamily\deffont[Script=Bengali]{Lohit-Bengali}

\author{\serifbb {শক্তি চট্টোপাধ্যায়}}%
\title{\serifbb {যখন বৃষ্টি নামলো}}%
\date{}

\begin{document}
\deffont %Default font used for the document
\maketitle
\noindent
\begin{center}বুকের মধ্যে বৃষ্টি নামে নৌকা টলোমলো\\
কূল ছেড়ে আজ অকূলে যাই এমনও সম্বল\\
নেই নিকটে - হয়ত ছিল বৃষ্টি আসার আগে\\
চলচ্ছক্তিহীন হয়েছি, তাই কি মনে জাগে\\
পোড়োবাড়ির স্মৃতি? আমার স্বপ্নে মেশা দিন\\
চলচ্ছক্তিহীন হয়েছি, চলচ্ছক্তিহীন।\vspace{.5in}\\
বৃষ্টি নামলো যখন আমি উঠোন-পানে একা,\\
দৌড়ে গিয়ে ভেবেছিলাম তোমার পাব দেখা\\
হয়ত মেঘে-বৃষ্টিতে বা শিউলিগাছের তলে\\
আজানুকেশ ভিজিয়ে নিচ্ছো আকাশ-ছেঁচা জলে\\
কিন্তু তুমি নেই বাহিরে – অন্তরে মেঘ করে,\\
ভারি ব্যাপক বৃষ্টি আমার বুকের মধ্যে ঝরে!\end{center}
\end{document}
```

(You must use `\newfontfamily` insead of `\font\serifbb`).

For some adjustments, use custom config file, `config.cfg`:

```
\Preamble{xhtml, NoFonts}
\renewcommand\vspace[1]{
\HCode{<div class="vspace"></div>}
}
\Css{.vspace{height:.5em;}}
\Css{img[src*=ec-lmr]{display:none;}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

There is configuration for `\vspace` command and css declaration for hiding some unwanted images mysteriously generated by `tex4ht` (I said that this is experimental package!)

Unfortunately, I cannot get correct result with classical `ht(xe|lua)latex` scripts, so I used [make4ht](https://github.com/michal-h21/make4ht):

```
make4ht -u -c config -x trial.tex
```

`-u` switch set output file to utf-8, `-c` is for config file inclusion, `-x` is for xelatex

The result:

[image]

Comment: michal, Thanks for your reply. I have cloned make4ht. But can not build it. Can't see how to build. I tried those Make:htlatex() etc and not working.

Comment: you don't have to build it. you only have to clone it to local texmf dir (see https://github.com/michal-h21/make4ht#instalation), make file make4ht executable (chmod +x make4ht) and add make4ht dir to the path, so this script can be executed from anywhere