# Error using htlatex to convert to html on Windows (MiKTeX)

Tags: miktex, htlatex

I'm trying to convert a LaTeX document into HTML (or rather, I'm trying to output HTML instead of, say, PDF - is this the right way to say this?)

I used the advice of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39458 and tried writing this:

```
htlatex book.tex html "" -dhtml "--interaction=nonstopmode"
```

This actually worked great until I got the following error:

```
System call: copy figs/Correlation_examples.png html.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

I fiddled around with the copy command for a minute and then realized that the problem is that the forward slash (which is fine on Unix) needs to be a backwards slash on Windows (i.e., instead of **figs/** it needs to be **figs\**)

So on the one hand this should be a simple fix, but on other hand I'm having trouble finding which file to modify to make the fix.

My question:
Is there a way around this on MiKTeX on Windows?  I think that htlatex (and mk4tex, etc, etc) all appear to be compiled executables so I don't think it's possible to modify htlatex.exe myself (short of re-compiling/re-building MikTeX, of course).

Comment: Follow-on question: If I did want to report this as a bug, where do I do that?  MiKTeX has a GitHub page, but I don't see the normal button for 'Issues' on said page.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. Make a complete example.

Comment: Thank you for trying, @UlrikeFischer!
I'm trying to build "Think Stats 2", by Allen Downey.  The full repo is here:  https://github.com/AllenDowney/ThinkStats2 .
I want to apologize for not having a much smaller, much more reasonable repo case.  I'm not the author and don't normally write LaTeX myself.

Comment: To add some insight: the problem is that some image is in a subdir, and it's not able to use the windows "copy.exe" command with the slashes tilting the wrong way.  Hopefully this might help find a repro case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not on Windows and don't use Miktex, so I cannot test this issue. Nevertheless, I think that I can answer some of your questions:

- `htlatex` and similar scripts aren't binary executables, they are only batch scripts which call LaTeX with special configuration for `tex4ht` three times, and then it calls `tex4ht` and `t4ht` binaries, which are responsible for the actual conversion and calling commands. You can't modify the way how file copy works from these scripts.
- you can configure command which are used for image conversion, copying etc. in the `tex4ht.env` file. It is located in `texmf-dist/tex4ht/base/win32/tex4ht.env` in the TeX distribution root. You can copy this file to the directory in which is your document and find the following lines:

  ```
  % t4ht -d%%2                                                              
  Mmove %%1 %%2%%3                                                                                                                                      
  Ccopy %%1 %%2%%3
  ```

The line starting with `Ccopy` defines the command which is used for file copying. You can replace `copy` with some command which supports forward slashes and which can copy the source file to the correct subdirectory of the destination directory. I hope that such command exists for Windows.

- as an alternative, you can use [make4ht](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/make4ht?lang=en), which is alternative command for `tex4ht` invocation. It should correctly copy the files to destination directory even on Windows. Try the following command:

  ```
  make4ht -u -d html book.tex
  ```