# Mouse Control of 360 Video in Beamer?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, animations, video

I am making a mesh of Games of Thrones video for 360 video, motivated by Zuckerberg's video today about GoT where you can move mouse 360 in the beginning, in Matlab. 
I am thinking where to show the output. 
I can generate any format from the code but not sure if the user interaction can be hold in any beamer's output formats, as I can understand in the discussion [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58805/13173) about *Beamer and JavaScript in a web browser*.

I would like to embed such a 360 mouse control in my beamer presentation, stub [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/279909/13173), for instance, in any format. 
HTML is sufficient and can be done with Beamer ([here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25309/13173)). 
There may be some elements missing in Beamer which does not allow the user interaction. 
In such a case, I would like to understand what.

Example of Mark's 360 GoT video

[image]

Pseudocode

```
%% Sources
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98446/13173 for 2D animation
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{ocgx}
\tikzset{ocg button/.style={circle,inner sep=.25em,switch ocg with mark on={#1}{}}}
\tikzset{base/.style={baseline=-0.5ex}}

\newcommand{\function}{x ...}
\newcommand{\buttonUp}[2]{\tikz[base]\node[fill=#2!30,ocg button=#1]{};}
\newcommand{\buttonDown}[2]{\tikz[base]\node[fill=#2!30,ocg button=#2]{};}
\newcommand{\buttonLeft}[2]{\tikz[base]\node[fill=#2!30,ocg button=#3]{};}
\newcommand{\buttonRight}[2]{\tikz[base]\node[fill=#2!30,ocg button=#4]{};}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[b][0.5\textheight][c]{0.2\textwidth}
...
\end{minipage}%

\end{document}
```

### Planning Document

- Is Flash [Flex](http://flex.apache.org/) sufficient?
- I like Java API. How well does Java Flex compare to it?
- Blender. [JohannesB]

### 2D Mesh and viewer on .tex Document

- Data. Panorama.
- Package. `animate`.
- Stepping by 1°. This would require only 180 frames, keeping PDF size small.

### 3D Mesh and Viewer on .tex Document

- Data. 3D Panorama. I think this can be only a picture. How to get/make such a data?
- Package. `animate`.
- Stepping by 10°. This would require only 36x18=648 frames, not expanding PDF size.

Thread about making the datatype [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37298552/54964) in Stackoverflow.
[AlexG] The azimuth has a range of 0° to 360° while elevation ranges from -90° to +90° for a sphere and from 0° to +90° for the northern hemisphere. With 10° stepping in both coordinates this makes 36x18 for the whole sphere and 36x9 for the hemisphere.
ASCII example of equispaced font where 9 (=18/2) panorama pictures of the hemisphere on top of each other for each angle; everything can be in one picture

```
1 2 3 4 ... 34 35 36
___2D-panorama #1__ 1
___2D-panorama #2__ 2
________etc________ 3
___________________ 4
___________________ ...
___________________ 8
___2D-panorama_ #9_ 9
```

Viewer's metadata

- stepping angle
- projection algorithm without loosing data
- .png lossless compression

---

How can you have mouse control of video element in Beamer?

Comment: Honestly, as far as i am cocerned, this question could might as well be asking how to dig holes in your garden with an unplugged electrical chainsaw. Apart from the fact, that you could use the blade for shoveling, or attach some small spade using cable binders, using a real shovel seems to be the sane approach here.

Comment: The chance of actually starting it while digging is much too high. Ever moved a running chainsaw into the dirt? Don't. The result is not funny. *Dids: Do not try this at home*.

Comment: As i said, *i* think  using a pdf with flash is the wrong approach. A penguin is a good swimmer and you can mount wings on it and make it fly but ... the result might not be satisfactory.

Comment: @Johannes_B What's wrong with flash? It allows for more complex interactivity within html and can do so within PDF. Its documentation is public. Everyone can write players/plugins/VMs.

Comment: You can use [Flex](http://flex.apache.org/) to program Flash applications and embed them with the `media9` package as demonstrated here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98686 . Yet, I must admit that it may be a huge task to build a 3D scene viewer that way.

Comment: I really don't know how to start such a project. Maybe there is some Flash solution already available on the Web?

Comment: Perhaps it would be more constructive to ask @Johannes_B where shovels are to be had or which kind of shovel would be best for hole-digging in the relevant type of garden soil?

Comment: If i have understand it correctly, TeX (and so LaTeX) are (mainly) for typesetting static text, the pdf format allows stuff like Flash thingies to be included in pdf. In my point of view, that does not mean that LaTeX (just because it can generate a pdf) is also the tool to generate something flashy interactive like a video.

Comment: Unforetunately, i don't know how to generate a video (or what the goal here is).

Comment: I would certainly have a look at Blender though, those guys from the Blender community can do miracles

Answer (score 3):

A simple panorama viewer for panoramic images with a fixed *z*-axis can be built using the **`animate`** package. (AR required.)

The example uses a 360° image downloaded [here](https://cdn.eso.org/images/screen/potw1130a.jpg).

Clicking the buttons changes the view by 10°, [shift]+click by 1°.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{media9}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xsavebox}

\begin{document}
\xsavebox{PanoramaImg}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{potw1130a}}%
\xsavebox{PanoramaImg}{\thePanoramaImg\thePanoramaImg}%
\raisebox{-0.5\height}{\mediabutton[
  jsaction={
    var frm=anim['myPanorama'].frameNum;
    if(event.shift) frm--;
    else frm-=10;
    if(frm<0) frm+=360;
    anim['myPanorama'].frameNum=frm;
  }
]{\Huge$\triangleleft$}}%
\raisebox{-0.5\height}{%
  \begin{animateinline}[label=myPanorama,step,nomouse]{1}
    \multiframe{360}{dStep=0pt+\dimexpr\linewidth/360\relax}{
      \makebox[1.78\height][l]{\hspace{-\dStep}\makebox[0pt][l]{\thePanoramaImg}}
    }
  \end{animateinline}%
}%
\raisebox{-0.5\height}{\mediabutton[
  jsaction={
    var frm=anim['myPanorama'].frameNum;
    if(event.shift) frm++;
    else frm+=10;
    frm\%=360;
    anim['myPanorama'].frameNum=frm;
  }
]{\Huge$\triangleright$}}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Masi : Acrobat Reader

Comment: @Masi : The next problematic step would be the projection of the spherical data onto the rectangular viewport. This is beyond `animate`, I am afraid.  For `animate`, you need a fixed set of pre-fabricated frames to choose from (with the arrow keys).

Comment: @Masi: For example: If you restrict yourself to one hemisphere and you want to be able to freely step by 1° in azimuthal and in polar directions each. With `animate` this would require a total of 360x180=64800 pre-built frames, since we cannot do projection on the fly.

Comment: @Masi : No, I don't have any such data. Maybe stepping by 10° would be sufficient and would require only 36x18=648 frames. This could be manageable without the PDF to explode in size.

Comment: @Masi : I really don't know in which format such (photographic?) data are usually distributed. As I said, a matrix of 36x18 projections (=648 individual image files) of such data on a rectangular area would be required.

Comment: @Masi : Looks ok. Actually, we only need 9 rows for a hemisphere with 10° stepping ;-) . Perhaps a single large image containing the view matrix could be handled more easily.

Comment: @Masi : The azimuth has a range  of 0° to 360° while elevation ranges from -90° to +90° for a sphere and from 0° to +90° for the northern hemisphere. With 10° stepping in both coordinates this makes 36x18 for the whole sphere and 36x9 for the hemisphere.